# Ransom Note problem (Python) true or false with inputs in string need to use def and main

Tags: python, function

A kidnapper kidnaps you and writes a ransom note. He does not write it by hand to avoid having
his hand writing being recognized, so he uses a magazine to create a ransom note. We need to
find out, given the ransom string and magazine string, is it possible to create a given ransom
note. The kidnapper can use individual characters of words.
Here is how your program should work to simulate the ransom problem:
▪ your program should prompt the user to enter a long String to represent the magazine and
another short String to represent the required ransom note.
▪ your program needs to check if the magazine string contains all required characters in equal
or greater number present in the ransom note.
▪ your program should print true if it is possible to create the given ransom note from the
given magazine, and print false otherwise.
▪ Break up your code into a set of well-defined functions. Each function should include a
comment block that briefly describes it, its parameters and any return values.
Example: If the magazine string is “programming problems are weird”
If the ransom note is: “no see” your program should print true as all the characters in “no
see” exist in the magazine string.
If the ransom note is “no show” your program should print false as not all the characters
in “no show” exist in the magazine string as you can see the character ‘h’ does not exist.

this is what I did, however, at this stage I should be using def and **main** because its suppose to be more professional, and I did not. not sure how to make it fit within those parameters any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

mag=input('Enter magazine words:')
ran=input('Enter ransom note: ')

## Run loop to cycle through letters.

for i in range(0, 150): # Select range in which to check mag.
c = chr(i) # Use chr to return characters from string.

## Check characters in mag and ran. Also, if count mag is less than ran print false.

```
if(mag.count(c)<ran.count(c)):
    print('False')
    break
```

## If loop runs without any break else condition will be executed.

else:
print('True')

Comment: Are the lines of code supposed to represent one larger code block? It's not clear from the code snippet you've posted (and you should edit to reflect as such).

Comment: Please reformat your question separating *your* code from task remarks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) along with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
from collections import Counter

def remove_white_space(s: str) -> str:
    """Returns string with whitespace removed"""
    return "".join(s.strip())

def can_create_ransom_note(magazine: str, ransom_note: str) -> bool:
    """Checks if magazine contains enough of each non-whitespace character (case-sensitive) to form ransom note"""
    magazine_chars = Counter(remove_white_space(magazine))
    ransom_note_chars = Counter(remove_white_space(ransom_note))
    return all(magazine_chars[ch] >= count
               for ch, count in ransom_note_chars.items())

def main() -> None:
    magazine = input("Enter a long string representing the magazine:\n> ")
    ransom_note = input("Enter a string representing the ransom note:\n> ")
    could_create_ransom_note = can_create_ransom_note(magazine, ransom_note)
    print(could_create_ransom_note)
    print(f"It is{' ' if could_create_ransom_note else ' not '}possible to create the ransom note from that magazine")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter a long string representing the magazine:
> programming problems are weird
Enter a string representing the ransom note:
> no see
True
It is possible to create the ransom note from that magazine
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter a long string representing the magazine:
> programming problems are weird
Enter a string representing the ransom note:
> no show
False
It is not possible to create the ransom note from that magazine
```